# refresh page of all connected users after event from one user- type auction

Tags: c#, asp.net, page-refresh

I am working with .NET for my project. I would like to know how to set a refresh of a page for the the people seeing this page when an event occurs.
For example, an auction: people have their page refreshed automatically with the new amount when someone bids.

I want to display the quantity available of an item in real time. So all the users know how many are left and it is updated as soon as one user purchases an item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a candidate for [SignalR](http://signalr.net/).

Comment: I quickly read the introduction, it looks like a solution the way it is presented. I'll look into it. Thanks

Comment: it took me a while before I had the chance to finally start this project. I just tried the chat application of signalR and yes we are going to go with this solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
You could call a server side function frequently to check if a new event occured (someone bids) and then display an update.

[Some examples here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386404%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

You cannot trigger a refresh from server side - you need to do it the other way around - frequently check if something has changed.

Comment: `You cannot trigger a refresh from server side` - You can 'redirect' to the current page though: `Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)`, essentially the same thing.

Comment: I think I was not clear enough - I meant you cannot trigger a refresh for multiple users if one user bids.

Comment: @DGibbs I would be able to redirect to the current page. But how would I force the page of the all the user to redirect after one user bids?

Comment: That's what I meant - you can't. Every user needs to check for themselves if something changed (or the Timer can do it for them :) ).

Comment: @marcin.k.nowak I try to avoid an automatic timer because the content to be refresh takes some time to be displayed, and can be variable. I would not like to refresh the page while the content is still displaying.

Comment: You do not need to refresh the whole page every time (you could use an UpdatePanel). I suppose you could try making the method which checks if something changed (if someone bid) very quick and simple (so most of the calls would be super-fast an just doing nothing to the page). And when something changes, then you need to load the content anyway.

Comment: Candidate for setInterval(sendAjaxAndGetChanges, 1000). This will update FROM the client-side. If multiple users need to see it, they would also need the setInterval(sendAjaxAndGetChanges, 1000). You could modify the 1000 to your liking. The good part is that if you have a lean WebAPI and JSON, this would work very well. Also I would not use UpdatePanel and Timer because these are very slow in high-traffic environments they would come to a halt. Use jQuery's ajax method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with AJAX and setTimeOut(). Set a timer to trigger an AJAX let's say every 1 minute, and in the AJAX method you can check if there are not read Auctions or so, in other words, your logic, and if the conditions are satisfied, you can get the AJAX's return to perform, for example, a **window.navigate("auctionspage.html");** and redirects the user to a specific page. Be sure to check that the user did read the page so he won't be redirected again in the next setTimeOut() call.

Comment: setTimeout, not setTimeOut. And setTimeout only happens once... he needs the browser to check it every x seconds to see if updates appear. Doing it only once is not very useful